# Python Plots - Plotting a subplots in a subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a graph representing the changes as per the varying variables. The sample figure is shown below. [image: Sample Figure]

The idea is to plot subplot within a subplot. Note It is different from plotting a graph using subplot with a predefined number of rows and columns, i.e matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

Can I plot such figures using matplotlib/seaborn?

Comment: _The idea is to plot subplot[s] within a subplot_ but another idea is to draw a frame around each couple of subplots... you'd have to do all the geometry by yourself but it should work perfectly

Comment: Did you try to use an inset_axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have drawn the frames and placed the axes inside the frames, everything is based on the no. of subplots/frame, the no. of rows and columns of the frames' grid and the physical dimensions of the different elements.

I imagine that most of the code is self explanatory, except the part where we place the axes in the precise locations, that's stolen from the [Demo Fixed Size Axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_fixed_size_axes.html), if you see points in need of elucidation please ask

```
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import Divider, Size
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.mpl_axes import Axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

mm = lambda d: d/25.4

nplots = 2
wp, hp = mm(40), mm(28)
dxp, dyp = mm(16), mm(12)

nrows, ncols = 3, 2
wf, hf = nplots*(wp+dxp), hp+dyp
dxf, dyf = mm(10), mm(8)

xcorners, ycorners = (np.arange(dxf/2,ncols*(wf+dxf),wf+dxf),
                      np.arange(dyf/2,nrows*(hf+dyf),hf+dyf))

# plus 10 mm for suptitle
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(ncols*(wf+dxf), nrows*(hf+dyf)+mm(10))) 

rect = lambda xy: plt.Rectangle(xy, wf, hf,
                                transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans,
                                figure=fig,
                                edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')
fig.patches.extend([rect(xy) for xy in product(xcorners, ycorners)])

t = np.linspace(0,3.14,315); s = np.sin(t)

for nframe, (y, x) in enumerate(product(ycorners, xcorners), 1):
    for n in range(nplots):
        divider = Divider(fig, (0.0, 0.0, 1., 1.),
                          [Size.Fixed(x+0.7*dxp+n*(wp+dxp)), Size.Fixed(wp)],
                          [Size.Fixed(y+0.7*dyp           ), Size.Fixed(hp)],
                          aspect=False)
        ax = Axes(fig, divider.get_position())
        ax.set_axes_locator(divider.new_locator(nx=1, ny=1))
        ax.plot(t, s)
        fig.add_axes(ax)
        fig.text(x, y, 'Frame %d'%nframe, transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans)

figsize = fig.get_size_inches()
width = figsize[0]*25.4 # mm
fig.suptitle('Original figure width is %.2f mm - everything is scaled'%width)
fig.savefig('pippo.png', dpi=118, facecolor='#f8f8f0')
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou @gboffi for the nice and self-explanatory code.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to use Matplotlib to plot these graphs

You can follow the following example to create your own figure with the graphs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)  # Args ( Lines, Columns, Reference )
plt.plot(x, y, 'r')  # Reference will say what graph we are modding
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(y, x, 'g')
plt.show()
```

The code will create one graph like this:

[image]

And you can use `plt.xlabel('name')`, `plt.ylabel('name')` and `plt.title('name')` to define the labels and the title of your figure

Note: The code above will create one image with 2 graphs, and you can use this code inside another block of code to create the image that you want.

You can also use the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=5, figsize=(5, 5))
ax[0, 0].plot(x, y)  # The method ax is now one array and is referred by indexes
ax[0, 0].set_title('Title')
ax[1, 1].plot(x, y)
ax[1, 1].set_title('Title')
plt.tight_layout()  # It will separate the graphs to avoid overlays
plt.show()
```

It will create the following image:

[image]

Comment: Hello...The idea is not to plot using subplots, But to plot "subplots within subplots"